# Representing matrices as rectangles to indicate their dimension

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to represent Ax = b\ interms of rectangles so that viewers can appreciate the dimensions more intuitively. [image]

I would like to have the Matrix A in the center of the rectasngle and the labels as dimensions. I tried using tikz but I am unable to align the rectabgles. Any pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[draw, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=8mm, label=left:6, label=below:$10^5$] (A) {A};
\node[right=1mm of A] (p) {$\times$};
\node[draw, minimum width=8mm, minimum height=3cm, label=-60:$10^5$, label=6, right=1mm of p] (x) {x};
\node[right=1mm of x] (e) {$=$};
\node[draw, minimum size=8mm, label=right:6, label=6, right=1mm of e] (B) {B};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Update: with north alignment

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[draw, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=8mm, label=left:6, label=below:$10^5$] (A) {A};
\node[draw, minimum width=8mm, minimum height=3cm, label=left:$10^5$, label=6, below right= 0 and 8mm of A.north east] (x) {x};
\node[draw, minimum size=8mm, label=right:6, label=6, below right=0 and 8mm of x.north east] (B) {B};

\path (A.east) --  node{$\times$} (A-|x.west);
\path (B-|x.east)  -- node {$=$} (B.west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]